# Issue on ~/.bashrc, written file PATH is not correct

Tags: bash, go, visual-studio-code, path

I am downloading Go on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. I am following this tutorial and I can't progress from this part on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS4e4q9oBaU&t=1810s:

When I created that Main.go an error on VSC console shows up:

```
Failed to run '/usr/local/go/bin/go env' (cwd:/home/santiagoquinteros/code): 
Error: Command failed:/usr/local/go/bin/go env GOPATH GOROOT GOPROXY GOBIN GOMODCACHE
missing $GOPATH
```

If i write on the console for example this command, this shows up:

```
~$ go get github.com/nsf/gocode
missing $GOPATH
```

This is whats inside my ~/.bashrc:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=/home/santiagoquinteros/golib
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export GOPATH=$gopath:/home/santiagoquinteros/code
```

On the video since 19:10 to 25:15 these lines of code are created and I followed him without making something else, but for some reason VSC is redirecting itself to another PATH I didn't mention. I have created the two folders called "golib" and "code" in the correct directory too.

I have searched on these pages too but all their solutions doesn't help me:

```
https://golang.org/doc/install
https://gist.github.com/vsouza/77e6b20520d07652ed7d
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108003
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238895/go-cannot-find-goroot-directory-error-on-installing-go-in-wsl
```

Take note that I'm working on a user limited version of ubuntu 16.04 and this could be the main issue.

VSC stands for VisualStudioCode

Comment: Your snippet has lines in your `bashrc` contains `export` at the end of a line instead of the beginning of the next line. This will likely break your export statements if that wasn't a typo

Comment: Export was a typo and i have fixed it now, i don't know why either i have to put GOROOT, but if i don't write that my linux machine doesn't know where to find the GO folder, i don't know what could be producing the problem. The problem still persist.

Comment: Your "system" doesn't know anything about `GOROOT`, it's only used by the go command, and should not be needed (I found the section of the video that talks about `GOROOT`, and even though the author was told not to set it, they completely missed the point that it's not required and still recommend setting it)

Comment: Is it possible that your `HOME` env variable is somehow unset?. The default value for `GOPATH` is `$HOME/go` (which is why you shouldn't need to set `GOPATH`). Also, did you execute those statements in your shell, or login again? Adding lines to your `.bashrc` doesn't add them to your current environment (not to mention, these should be in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, and not in an rc file).

Comment: I have discovered that my Ubuntu machine had some problems aside a normal computer, this machine is from the company I am working (it isn't mine) and has some restrictions, some of which may be causing this kind of trouble. I got another computer, a windows computer and Go functions without any problems there. So I would say that this kind of issues only happens when working on a user limited context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the error message comes from https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.16/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/init.go#L207-L210

In the last line of your ~/.bashrc, you meant `export GOPATH=$GOPATH:...`, not `export GOPATH=$gopath:...`. Since $gopath is not set, your GOPATH would end up being `:/home/santiagoquinteros/code`. The above code doesn't like it.

As others said, you don't need to set `GOROOT`. With go1.16, the module mode is the default, so you probably don't need to set `GOPATH` but live with the default `GOPATH` which is `$HOME/go`.

Many things have changed recently. I recommend newer sets of materials like https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started, https://learn.go.dev, https://play-with-go.dev/ , ...